# 'heroku login' throws 'Error: unable to get local issuer certificate' in cmd

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

When I run 'heroku login' or any other heroku cli command on widows cmd I get this: `Error: unable to get local issuer certificate.`
I've typed in everything I've found online and nothing helped, at all. I am at a dead-end with my project now. I also uninstalled and reinstalled heroku cli because I have no idea what they do. How do I get heroku cli to work?

Comment: SSL stuff can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I have the techloq internet filter, it was a problem with that. I emailed them and the fixed it.